# Extracting data from a variable at the command-line

Tags: text-processing, command-line, variable

I have two variables  $dc_list and $TEST_VENUE . If I do echo in bash

```
echo $dc_list
{"active-production-dc":"sc-va1","standby-production-dc":"sc-tx2","active-integration-dc":"int-va1","standby-integration-dc":"int-tx3"}
```

And

```
echo $TEST_VENUE
standby-production-dc
```

Now I need to fetch the value for TEST_VENUE from dc_list.

I tried this:

```
dc=$(echo "$dc_list" | sed -e 's/^.*'"$TEST_VENUE"':"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/')  ---> This is not working
```

But If I hardcode,

```
dc=$(echo "$dc_list" | sed -e 's/^.*"standby-production-dc":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/')  ---> This works.
```

But I want to achieve from First sed. Any suggesttions for this?

Comment: Is that some sort of json output?

Comment: this appears to be a string representation of an associative array (json or otherwise) which you are attempting to manipulate in bash.  bash can natively handle associative arrays.  so why not consider building your "dc_list" as a bash associative array?:  http://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2012/10/17/bash-associative-array-examples/

Answer (score 1):

For **bash** you can use *parameter expansion*

```
result=${dc_list#*$TEST_VENUE\":\"}
result=${result%%\"*}
```

Comment: Great. Is it possible to get this in single line. I am trying to get this done in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
tr '"' _ <<< $dc_list | sed -n "s/.*${TEST_VENUE}_:_\([^_]*\).*/\1/p"
```

However, my advice would be don't use this, especially if the format of the `$dc_list` changes.
I recommend using a json parser. I would use something like [PHP function json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) but obviously there are other alternatives - probably python has something good too.

This example of using PHP's `json_decode()` works for me and would be far more reliable, of course it assumes you have a PHP cli SAPI available to you.
You could use this code directly in your shell script, I tested using zsh, but I expect it would work for bash too.

```
<< 'EOF' php -- "$dc_list" "$TEST_VENUE"
<?php
$a = json_decode($argv[1]);
echo $a->{$argv[2]} . PHP_EOL;
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

For JSON data, use a JSON parser such as [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)

```
$ jq -r ".[\"$TEST_VENUE\"]" <<< "$dc_list" 
sc-tx2
```